# How to fix sending headers with axios post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, http-headers, http-post

I use `axios` to send a POST HTTP request with some binary data like this:

```
axios.post(url, input, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}})
```

When I got an `Bad request` error I printed out the request headers:

```
  "headers" : { 
    "common": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    },
    "delete": {},
    "get": {},
    "head": {},
    "post": {
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    },
    "put": {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "patch": {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  }
```

I overrode the default headers (see below) and got `Ok` instead `Bad request`

```
axios.defaults.headers = {"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}
```

So the problem is fixed but I don't like overriding `axios` defaults. How would you suggest use `axios.post` to send the header correctly ?

Comment: You need to separately specify the `content-type` header for each request to match the type of data you're sending.  The axios doc is very clear about how to send headers with a specific request.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I did not find it in the documentation (https://github.com/axios/axios). Could you point me out to a specific example ?

Comment: [These](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) are all the options for any axios request.  Included in that list is the `headers`.